# Is there ever a reason NOT to include the module name when calling a helper method in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When working with helper methods in Rails, it's possible to create a method in a helper file and then call the method in the view without referring to the helper module:

```
// application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper

   def foobar
      return "foo"
   end

end

// index.html.erb
<%= foobar %>
```

But if you want to avoid naming conflicts, you can also tie in the name of the helper module to the method you're calling, like this:

```
// application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper

   def self.foobar
      return "foo"
   end

end

// index.html.erb
<%= ApplicationHelper.foobar %>
```

Am I right in thinking that always doing the second approach is best practice for using a helper method in Rails, or is there sometimes a reason to not do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Rails convention dictates the former](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html), rather than the latter. Naming conflicts should be avoided by invoking descriptive method names – that is, `truncate_name` is better than `truncate` (so long as it's a name that's being truncated) – rather than namespacing via the module name.

If you're still at a loss, consider what the Rails core does: the [`FormHelper` class's](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html)  `form_for` function is invoked using `form_for`, *not* `FormHelper.form_for`. This convention holds true for the vast majority of Rails helper functions.

Another consideration: when utilizing Rails' default generator, a helper is created for each generated resource by default. It's common practice to define any helper functions *that are specific to the resource* within that resource's designated helper file. In contrast, helper functions that are applicable across the application should be defined in `application_helper.rb`, rather than in a resource specific helper.

Basically, if you're a strict adherent to Rails DRY principles, you'd want to distill your helper method names to their most elegant forms. If that's the case, it seems preferable to simply invoke `concatenate_names(['Alvin', 'Simon', 'Theodore'])`, rather than creating a new `NamesHelper` module and invoking `NamesHelper.concatenate(['A', 'S', 'T'])`.